# How can I restore my Windows system after the PC is booted into DOS from USB drive?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-vista, ms-dos

My PC with Windows Vista failed to boot. The screen showed that the boot device was not found. I think the boot area of the hard drive was damaged. Then I created a boot USB drive with DOS system, and now I can successfully boot into my machine. I can found drive D, so all files are there on the hard drive. My question is, how can I restore the Windows Vista system on the hard drive. Is there any command line that I can use to repair the boot area and restore the Windows Vista, since I only have DOS command line console now! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your MBR and/or bootsector got overwritten. Boot your PC from Vista's DVD and start the command prompt (Repair computer -> Command prompt). Then type `BOOTREC /FIXMBR` and `BOOTREC /FIXBOOT`. If that still doesn't help enter command prompt again and type `BOOTREC /REBUILDBCD`.

If you can't boot your PC from DVD for some reason, there is a tool called *Windows USB/DVD Download Tool* available to download from MS pages which will help you convert Vista's ISO image into bootable USB drive (I have never tested it though).